# Standard URL Normalization - Java

Tags: java, url, normalization

I would like to ask if there's any Java package or library that have the standard URL normalization?

**5 Components of URL Representation**

http://www[dot]example[dot]com:8040/folder/exist?name=sky#head

1. scheme: *http*
2. authority: *www.example.com:8040*
3. path: */folder/exist*
4. query: *?name=sky*
5. fragment: *#head*

**The 3 types of standard URL normalization**

*Syntax-Based Normalization*

- Case normalization – convert all letter at scheme and authority components to lower case
- Percent-encoded normalization – decode any percent-encoded octet that corresponds to unreserved character, such as %2D for hyphen and %5 for underscore
- Path segment normalization – remove dot-segments from the path component, such as ‘.’ and ‘..’

*Scheme-Based Normalization*

- Add trailing ‘/’ after the authority component of URL
- Remove default port number, such as 80 for http scheme
- Truncate the fragment of URL

*Protocol-Based Normalization*

- Only appropriate when the results of accessing the resources are equivalent
- For example, example.com/data is directed to example.com/data/ by origin server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
URI uri = URI.create("http://www.example.com:8040/folder/exist?name=sky#head");
String scheme = uri.getScheme();
String authority = uri.getAuthority();
// ...
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URI.html

Answer (score 5):

As others have mentioned, [java.net.URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) and/or [java.net.URI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) are some obvious starting points.

Here some other options:

1. [Galimatias](http://galimatias.mola.io/) (Spanish for "gibberish") appears to be an opinionated and relatively popular URL normalization library for Java. The source code can be found at [github.com/smola/galimatias](https://github.com/smola/galimatias).

   > galimatias started out of frustration with java.net.URL and java.net.URI. Both of them are good
   >   for basic use cases, but severely broken for others
2. The [github.com/sentric/url-normalization](https://github.com/sentric/url-normalization) library provides another (unusual, in my opinion) approach where it reverses the domain portion; e.g. "com.stackoverflow" instead of "stackoverflow.com".

You can find other variations, sometimes implemented in languages such as Python, Ruby, and PHP on Github.

Answer (score 0):

What about `java.net.URL` [set()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#set%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)?